# Unable to switch users in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, switch-user

Whenever I try to switch users in Ubuntu 12.04 it goes to a black screen with a cursor and hangs.  If I do the ctrl-alt-F6 (or any F1-6 button for that matter) it will switch to a command prompt and then if I switch back to ctrl-alt-F7 I'm presented with the login screen that you get when you return from a screenlock.  Is this a bug in Ubuntu or does something need reconfigured?

Answer (score 0):

How was the user's creation performed?

If the home folder of new user was not created, you can create like this:

```
sudo adduser <username>
```

**Caution:** This is not the same as the `useradd` command. But, it is easier and safer to use GNOME Control Center or `users-admin`.